# Install Google Seesaw Load Balancer

Tags: load-balancing, lvs

I have been trying to setup [Google Seesaw](https://github.com/google/seesaw) which is a load balancer based on LVS but have been unsuccessful so far following the directions [on the index.md and /doc/getting_started.md). It is stated quite clearly there is no support so I understand not getting much feedback from the github page however, I would be grateful for any guidance. I have been unable to start the seesaw service but issuing a `systemctl status seesaw_watchdog` shows 4/5 services running except seesaw_engine and checking the logs seems it doesn't recognize the backend entry in my cluster.pb file despite it being a required field the way I understand it(I simply edited the example found [here](https://github.com/google/seesaw/blob/master/etc/seesaw/cluster.pb.example) ). Any pointers appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seesaw is a bit of a beast to get working and there's hardly any documentation out there for it, as you have discovered I'm sure. You do need the backend section and it will not work without that; that's the actual servers behind the LB. Is that in your config still or did you remove it completely? I had to tweak the examples a bit to get things working properly. I would be happy to provide you with my working cluster.pb if you would like?

I have managed to get it working but I'm having difficulties with multiple seesaw nodes - The VIP moves between the two nodes nicely but the load balanced application is not accessible after a failover from one node to another, when I stop the seesaw services on the passive node then it all works again. Again, if I failover back the other way (with both running) then the application isn't accessible until I stop the services on the other node. It's clearly a config error but I'm struggling to work out what it is at the moment. Has anyone got it all working that would like to share cluster.pb and seesaw.cfg examples for both of us that are struggling with Seesaw configuration here please?

Comment: This should likely be a comment, because you are not providing information on how to fix the problem. If you want to post the config as a fix, that may be valid.

Comment: It's still in the config but it seems it's been flagged as invalid, can you share your config?